# Showing the json data in anychart.js Table layout(Table view)

Tags: html, asp.net, anychart

I am using anychart.js and want to show the series data into table layout(JSON response), I am using JSON format, I have created the other charts but the table layout is different, when I see the JSON configuration I don't understand the close point, current point, segments, arguments. Are those objects required for table layout? Could anyone help me in showing the data to the Table layout in anychart. Or the JSON data using anychart can display tables.

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle of what you have that is not working? Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrssj0gr/

Comment: this is the fiddle url in which mentioned the json data  and the ajax call which i am using.

Comment: you may use the json formatter (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to view the json data

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little why do you need to use the AnyChart table layout? The point is that Anychart supports the toHtmlTable() method:
https://api.anychart.com/8.0.1/anychart.core.Chart#toHtmlTable
it gets the chart data and creates the HTML table with it:
https://playground.anychart.com/api/8.0.1/core/anychart.core.Chart.toHtmlTable-plain
Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Oh Great, This is what i was looking for. I didn't check this example instead I was checking the Table layout to show the data in which json configuration was so complicated and other attempt was trying to show data using jquery. Thanks for providing this link from anychart. api.anychart.com/8.0.1/anychart.core.Chart#toHtmlTable